# Java - Youtube API: UploadVideo returns [error: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\users\myprofile\.oauth-credentials]

Tags: java, api, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I'm having a lot of trouble with the Youtube API UploadVideo example code FOR JAVA.

It can be found here: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples.  Just download the zip, follow the readme and enter client key, client secret, & api key in .json file provided. You create profile in google at http://code.google.com/apis/console.  You can follow installation instruction videos on youtube.

I was wondering if I could get some feedback on this problem.  I get this error when I run:

```
com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\Myprofile\oauth-credentials
com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\Myprofile\oauth-credentials
```

Does anyone else have this problem?  I'm assuming it's fairly common among users.

I get this error every time it tries to create a /.oauth-credentials folder under C:\Users\Myname.  What should I do to resolve this issue? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your service is already running. Kill the old instance, than it should work again. The needed info in your exception is this: "Address already in use:"

Comment: did you solved this issue